# Configuring Angular2 project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, angular, npm

I need help configuring Angular2 project in eclipse with npm.

I followed the 5-min starting guide, but when I create the node_modules folder inside the project folder, the building process is infinite (building, syncronizing with Tern server and more), so I just could not make this work. Tried excluding the folder from various Validators. Are there any specific validators to do this?

Does node_modules folder need to be inside the project directory? Inside the WebContent folder? I tried Static and Dynamic web projects.

When I'm not using npm but putting specific files inside a lib folder and referencing them directly, everything works fine, but I want to use npm the correct way.

Thank you!

Comment: If you want develop Angular2 project with TypeScript please see https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started Tern is for Angular1

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer I'm the author of [Angular2 Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started).

It seems that you have installed [AngularJS Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started), but it's for Angular1 and not Angular2.

If you wish to develop an Angular2 application with TypeScript please install [Angular2 Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started).

For your problem about `syncronizing with Tern server` (process is infinite), it's because you need to exclude the `node_modules` folder to avoid parsing JS files with tern coming from node_modules. To exclude this folder you must convert your project to `JavaScript Project` and check that `Include Path` excludes"node_modules" (it should be done if you convert your project to JavaScritpt Project):

[image: JSDT Include Path]

Comment: Thanks, I will try this!

Comment: Will I still need to do the following: Convert the project to AngularJS project, Enable Typescript Builder, Add Typescript support?

Comment: Please read https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/TypeScript-BuildPath and https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/TypeScript-Compiler#on-save